# check if fieldvalues exist?

Tags: sql, mysql

i want to check if a column contains any fieldvalues in a table.

cause i want to get the fieldvalues in a column and do something with them, but first i have to check whether they exist or not.

i have tried:

```
$query = "SELECT anonymous_username FROM users";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die ("Couldn't execute query: " . mysqli_error($conn));

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
 {
  echo "exists";
 }
}
```

but even when all the fields for that column were empty it echoed back 'exists'. so how can i do it?

EDIT: google is your friend:

```
 $query = "SELECT anonymous_username FROM users WHERE anonymous_username <> '' AND anonymous_username IS NOT NULL";
```

Comment: Are you sure that specific line echoes the “exists”?

Comment: yes, and i found the solution now..se my updated post

Comment: Rather than handling it on the data layer, can you do your logic on the business layer, where you do something like: if(!isset($row)) { //your logic }.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to check if any row has a non-NULL, non-empty `anonymous_username` column, you could:

```
SELECT count(*) as Num
FROM users
WHERE LENGTH(anonymous_username) > 0
```

In PHP, you can retrieve the number like:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result );
$rowcount = $row['num'];
```

Answer (score 3):

[`mysqli_affected_rows`](http://php.net/mysqli_affected_rows) is only for queries that change data like `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `REPLACE` or `DELETE`. For `SELECT` use [`mysqli_num_rows`](http://php.net/mysqli_num_rows).

Comment: but it still didnt helped because the result is still 1. it gets the field although its empty. basically i want to check if any fields in one column has a value or not.